# How to get system's closed caption font size?

Tags: uwp, media-player, closed-captions

I want to get system's closed caption font style, and I referd [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/zh-cn/uwp/api/windows.media.closedcaptioning?view=winrt-19041). So far everything is good, except the font size.

According to [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/zh-cn/uwp/api/windows.media.closedcaptioning.closedcaptionproperties.fontsize?view=winrt-19041#Windows_Media_ClosedCaptioning_ClosedCaptionProperties_FontSize), `ClosedCaptionProperties.FontSize` returns enum `ClosedCaptionSize`, see code

```
        switch (Windows.Media.ClosedCaptioning.ClosedCaptionProperties.FontSize)
        {
            case Windows.Media.ClosedCaptioning.ClosedCaptionSize.FiftyPercent:
                richtextblock.FontSize = 50;
                break;
            case Windows.Media.ClosedCaptioning.ClosedCaptionSize.OneHundredPercent:
                richtextblock.FontSize = 100;
                break;
            case Windows.Media.ClosedCaptioning.ClosedCaptionSize.OneHundredFiftyPercent:
                richtextblock.FontSize = 150;
                break;
            case Windows.Media.ClosedCaptioning.ClosedCaptionSize.TwoHundredPercent:
                richtextblock.FontSize = 200;
                break;
            default:
                richtextblock.FontSize = 100;
                break;
        }
```

I set `FontSize` to the corresponding number, although I know it's a percentage.

The final reslut is different from system.

So what's the exact `FontSize` of these enums???

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The enumeration does not give a specific value, but a percentage. Obviously you also noticed this.

The percentage depends on a reference value. Generally speaking, the most common default font size of UWP is 14, but in MediaTransportControls, the default font size is usually 12.

So `Windows.Media.ClosedCaptioning.ClosedCaptionSize.OneHundredFiftyPercent` should be **12*1.5=18**.

---

**Update**

Sorry, I need to explain further about the font size of the CC.

The size of CC is affected by many factors:

*1. The settings of the subtitle file itself.*

For example, SRT file support font setting. `<font color="red">{\fs25}` means a line of subtitles with a `FontSize` of 25 and a `Foreground` of red.

*2. Affected by the size of the current window*

The controls for displaying subtitles are integrated in `TimedTextSourcePresenter` (a Grid inside MediaPlayerElement). For `TimedTextSourcePresenter`, you can think of it as a `ViewBox`. It will scale the internal elements according to the size of the current control.

In summary, the Closed Caption in `MediaPlayerElement` has a base font size, but this font size is not necessarily equal to the font size finally rendered.

Thanks.

Comment: 12 seems too small and is't cc's font size. I set default to 50 and looks OK.

Comment: I wonder if anyone can view the source code or is there any information about the CC control. Also I can't find cc control in `MediaTransportControls.xaml`

Comment: Hello, I'm sorry I didn't explain clearly, I have modified my answer. The font size of Closed Caption is affected by many factors and cannot be expressed with an exact value

Comment: Hmm, we want to create a second cc, the same size. It seems now way now...

Comment: Currently `MediaPlayerElement` does not support displaying two closed caption at the same time. So you can consider modifying the SRT file to bilingual subtitles, or use `ViewBox` as the container for the second CC control, overlaid on `MediaPlayerPresenter` (need to modify the control template of `MediaPlayerElement`).

Comment: Modify srt seems impossible, cause we use srt returned from server. So I will open another question, can you create a sample using viewbox?

Comment: I made some attempts and answered it in your another question