# How to create a second/bilingual subtitle, the same size to MediaPlayerElement's CC

Tags: uwp, media-player, closed-captions

For some reason, `MediaPlayerElement`'s CC font size is affected by many factors, I can't get the exact font size. Refer to SO link, [How to get system's closed caption font size?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62321361/how-to-get-systems-closed-caption-font-size).

So do anyone has ideas how to create a second/bilingual subtitle, the same size to MediaPlayerElement's CC?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `ControlTemplate` that modifies `MediaPlayerElement` to create your custom subtitle control.

Making a complete subtitle control is more complicated. I will only provide one idea here.

**1. We need to create a control class derived from `MediaPlayerElement` as our test case.**

```cs
public class CustomMediaPlayerElement:MediaPlayerElement
{
    public string SecondCaption
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(SecondCaptionProperty); }
        set { SetValue(SecondCaptionProperty, value); }
    }
    public static readonly DependencyProperty SecondCaptionProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("SecondCaption", typeof(string), typeof(CustomMediaPlayerElement), new PropertyMetadata(""));

}
```

We add a dependency property of `SecondCaption`, which is the text of the second subtitle we are currently displaying. In the future, we can switch the displayed text with a timer.

**2. Create the custom control template**

Since MediaPlayerElement's CC font size is variable, we can use `ViewBox` for simulation.

```xml
<Style TargetType="local:CustomMediaPlayerElement" x:Key="BasicMediaStyle">
    <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
    <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
    <Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="False" />
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="local:CustomMediaPlayerElement">
                <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
                    <Border Background="Transparent" />
                    <Image  x:Name="PosterImage"
            Visibility="Collapsed"
            Source="{TemplateBinding PosterSource}"
            Stretch="{TemplateBinding Stretch}" />
                    <MediaPlayerPresenter x:Name="MediaPlayerPresenter"
            IsFullWindow="{TemplateBinding IsFullWindow}"
            Stretch="{TemplateBinding Stretch}"
            MediaPlayer="{TemplateBinding MediaPlayer}" />
                    <ContentPresenter     x:Name="TransportControlsPresenter"
            Visibility="{TemplateBinding AreTransportControlsEnabled}" IsTapEnabled="False"/>
                    <Grid x:Name="TimedTextSourcePresenter" />
                    <Grid x:Name="SecondTimedTextSourceContainer">
                        <Viewbox>
                            <Grid>
                                <TextBlock Text="{TemplateBinding SecondCaption}" FontSize="15" VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
                                       HorizontalAlignment="Center" TextAlignment="Center" Foreground="White"/>
                            </Grid>
                        </Viewbox>
                    </Grid>
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

**3. Add addition properties to make the subtitle display the correct size**

If we only write as above, we will end up with a `TextBlock` that fills the entire screen. In order for the `ViewBox` to work as we expect, we need to add some new attributes to make the container where the subtitles are the right size.

*CustomMediaPlayerElement.cs*

```cs
public double SourceWidth
{
    get { return (double)GetValue(SourceWidthProperty); }
    set { SetValue(SourceWidthProperty, value); }
}

public static readonly DependencyProperty SourceWidthProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register("SourceWidth", typeof(double), typeof(CustomMediaPlayerElement), new PropertyMetadata(double.NaN));


public double SourceHeight
{
    get { return (double)GetValue(SourceHeightProperty); }
    set { SetValue(SourceHeightProperty, value); }
}

public static readonly DependencyProperty SourceHeightProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register("SourceHeight", typeof(double), typeof(CustomMediaPlayerElement), new PropertyMetadata(double.NaN));
```

*CustomeMediaPlayerElement.xaml*

```xml
...
<Viewbox>
    <Grid Height="{TemplateBinding SourceHeight}" Width="{TemplateBinding SourceWidth}">
        <TextBlock Text="{TemplateBinding SecondCaption}" FontSize="15" VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
               HorizontalAlignment="Center" TextAlignment="Center" Foreground="White"/>
    </Grid>
</Viewbox>
...
```

---

**How to use**

```xml
<controls:CustomMediaPlayerElement SecondCaption="Hello World" x:Name="MyPlayer"
                                   AreTransportControlsEnabled="True" Style="{StaticResource BasicMediaStyle}"
                                   />
```

```cs
private async Task LoadVideo(StorageFile videoFile)
{
    var player = new MediaPlayer();
    var source = MediaSource.CreateFromStorageFile(videoFile);
    player.Source = source;
    player.MediaOpened += Media_Opened;
    MyPlayer.SetMediaPlayer(player);
}

private async void Media_Opened(MediaPlayer sender, object args)
{
    await Dispatcher.RunAsync(Windows.UI.Core.CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () =>
    {
        MyPlayer.SourceWidth = sender.PlaybackSession.NaturalVideoWidth;
        MyPlayer.SourceHeight = sender.PlaybackSession.NaturalVideoHeight;
    });
}
```

In this way, you can get a subtitle control that will scale with `MediaPlayerElement`, and modify the `SecondCaption` with the timer to achieve the function of subtitles.

But as I said before, it is complicated to implement a complete subtitle control. This is just a way to add a new subtitle control, you need to customize according to your needs.

Thanks.

Comment: Thanks, I will try later.

Comment: Hi, did you encounter any problems during the test? If so, please feel free to ask

Comment: Hi, Richard. I tried `ViewBox`, it seems not a perfect solution. When there is only one word, the font size is too large. https://imgur.com/a/454e44D. When too many words, the font size became small. https://imgur.com/Oahvb9T. So this way works but not the best.

Comment: Hello, I'm sorry I didn't explain clearly. If you just put a `TextBlock` in the `ViewBox`, because of the lack of container, the `TextBlock` will fill the entire control. This is why we need introduce two additional properties, `SourceWidth` and `SourceHeight`, to set the subtitle container to the same size as the video source, so as to ensure that the subtitles appear in the correct position and the appropriate size. In addition, you can also set the subtitle TextBlock to set `MaxWidth` and `TextWrapping` to make the subtitles wrap.